# How do I get the array value where the key, which is the number, is the next lowest value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

if I have this array in javascript:

```
array[1] = 'blue';
array[25] = 'green';
array[50] = 'yellow';
array[75] = 'orange';
array[100] = 'red';
```

and I have:

```
number = 35
```

how do I get to:

```
output = 'green';
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you try writing a function which gives you the first number smaller than 35, assuming you have an array [100, 75, 50, 25, 1]?

Comment: Hint: `Object.keys(array)` gives you `["1", "25", "50", "75", "100"]`. Use that array to do a binary search, then your solution will be of order `O(log(N))` where `N` is the number of colors (5), not `array.length` (101).

Comment: @Matt: They keys are returned in arbitrary order, so you can't do a binary search.

Comment: @Guffa Good point, thanks. So one should use `Object.keys(array)` and do a linear search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your array is setup like that, including all the empty slots, you could do something like this.

```
var i = 35;

while ( ! array[--i]) {}

array[i]; // "green"
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yqe0haL/).

However, if you're trying to show the relationship between those numbers to colours, you should use an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `hasOwnProperty()` to check if an `index` is really a property of the `array`.(For both arrays as well as `array-like` objects) It is `true` only if a value has been assigned at that particular index. The first valid index below `35`, would contain `green`.

```
   var i = 35;
   while(i >= 0){
        if(array.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            console.log(array[i]);
            break;
        }
      i--;
    }

  console.log(i) // gives you 25, which is the next valid index below 35.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstLessThanX = function (x) {
  var array = [100, 75, 50, 25, 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i] < x) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }
  return 'All values greater than or equal to ' + x;
};

array[ firstLessThanX(35) ] // 'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items in the array, and check which one of the items that are smaller than the number, is closest to the number:

```js
var array = [];

array[1] = 'blue';
array[25] = 'green';
array[50] = 'yellow';
array[75] = 'orange';
array[100] = 'red';

var n = 35, min = null, value;

for (x in array) {
  var diff = n - x;
  if (diff >= 0 && (min == null || diff < min)) {
    min = diff;
    value = array[x];
  }
}

// show result is Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(value);
```